# Imagesource is not set when string is coming from variable

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am setting an imagesource like so:

```
    // get real thumbnail
obj.thumbnailSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fullList[i].thumbnail)));
```

The result is an empty frame where there is supposed to be a picture.

With stop points i managed to find out that while on this position `fullList[i].thumbnail` gives this exact string:

```
"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"
```

If I now take this long string and simply add it into the code, replacing the `fullList[i].thumbnail` part, the image is rendered fine (you can also try this string in HTML). It will give you (and gave me) the right foto.

Again, setting this from the variable containing this string, no picture is shown.

Is there something odd with imagesource I am overseeing?

(This is the type):

```
public class User
{
   public string userEmail { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
    public string isFirstLogIn { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }

    public Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource thumbnailSource { get; set; }

}
```

Edit: This is even more strange:

What DOES work would be this:

```
            byte[] res = Convert.FromBase64String(fullList[i].thumbnail);
            // get real thumbnail
            obj.thumbnailSource = ImageSource.FromStream(
                            () => new MemoryStream(res));
```

I am simply converting the string into a byte array and add the byte array to the stream. This works!
Doing it immediately, nothing is rendered.

What is going on?

Comment: if everything else is fine , then I think its just a simple case of raising the property , you need to derive your `User` model with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `thumbnailSource` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this has memory implications, so I'm open for suggestion.

Instead of using `new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fullList[i].thumbnail))` to get a `Stream`, I return the image byte array from the `GetDraftImageAsyncBytes()` method.

Instead of loading a stream directly, in the **ImageSource** lambda I create a new one each time:

```
var bytes = await _imageDownloader.GetDraftImageAsyncBytes();
MainImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

The `bytes` will stay in memory, and the stream will be `disposed` each time but also recreated when Xamarin call the lambda function during rendering.